# Android - Can't see my_app background when i use it on my phone

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, background

Here my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/my_background"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp" >
```

I don't know why, but when i test my_app on the avd i see it perfectly, but when i use my phone (galaxy nexus) everything work good, but i can't see my custom background on the activity!

Comment: check where have u put it... it is good practice if u put it in res/drawable folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are the different stalks of the drawable folder too. Make sure it is in the res/drawable folder and not in a certain one like drawable-xhdpi because your phone might not be the same as that, although your emulator might be. That means that when you load it onto your phone, it will look in the wrong directory as your phone isn't xhdpi or whatever and so won't find it.

Comment: i put "my_background.png" in all my drawable folders(drawable, drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi and drawable-xhdpi), but nothing...

Comment: fixed! it was a problem of the png image.

Comment: Nice job! What exactly was the problem with the .png image?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the background image was shown in the editor of eclipse but not on my device when I ran the app.

I did the following and solved the problem:

1. Open the background image with a image editor (paint or photoshop).
2. Save the image.
3. Overwrite the background image in the drawable folder with the recently saved image.
4. Run the app.